# django model.charfield - unicode or not unicode

Tags: django, encoding, django-models

I transfered my project to another computer and get an error while running a view.

I'm getting some informations of a model and want to save them to XML by using XMLGenerator.

On the one computer it works fine, `type()` of the `model.charField()` returns "unicode"

On the new computer it did not work, `type()` of the `model.charField()` returns "str"

The working computer has Python 2.7.2

The not working computer has Python 2.5.2

So on the not working computer I did not get unicode which can be handled by XMLGenerator. I tried to work around the problem by running .decode("utf-8") on the string which is served by the model and it worked.

But how can I know what encoding the string is? I guessed now that it has the same encoding as in the database but am I right?

regards Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

could you please check the mysql collation settings? if those are also the same?
from django doc: 
"In many cases, this default will not be a problem. However, if you really want case-sensitive comparisons on a particular column or table, you would change the column or table to use the utf8_bin collation. The main thing to be aware of in this case is that if you are using MySQLdb 1.2.2, the database backend in Django will then return bytestrings (instead of unicode strings) for any character fields it receive from the database."
[see django doc collation settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings)

Comment: The database which gives unicode has latin1-collation and the database which gives str has utf-8-collation.

I heared that MySQL with utf-8 does not serve the strings as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have this:

```
a = unicode('a')
b = str('b')
```

A fast check is to do:

```
print type(a)
print type(b)
```

If you want to validate them you can do:

```
if isinstance(a, str):

if isinstance(a, unicode):
```

A way would to to typecast the content:

```
c = str(a)
d = unicode(b)
```